# convert html with css to PDF using jquery/javascript

Tags: html, pdf-generation, html2canvas, html2pdf

I want to convert a HTML report to PDF with CSS. I have look through the google and I found jsPDF. But the problem with jsPDF is that it does not supprt CSS. To make the CSS work I have used html2canvas. But it does not work properly.

Can anyone suggest me a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If it's for your own use, install a pdf printer driver on your computer (there are loads of them if you google, but you probably already have one installed anyway) then just print the report to pdf.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a script.

Comment: easy: `window.print();`

Comment: It does not serve the purpose.
I want to show the report in a pdf in browser.